# Use \bgroup and \egroup to set some pre and post code to a macro

Tags: macros, boxes, programming, grouping

Why isn’t it possible to use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` in this way?

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\precode{\fbox\bgroup}
\def\postcode{\egroup}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\precode#1\postcode}

\begin{document}
\mymacro{Text}
\end{document}
```

I know that I can store the argument to a box or smiley use `\fbox`in the definition of `\mymacro` directly but the application of this MWE is a little more complex so that these two way won’t work. Now I wonder why this code gives no error but gives no text either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, only a few commands, say, TeX box primitives like `\hbox`, can use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` like this. An example:

```
\newcommand\premybox{\leavevmode\hbox\bgroup\bfseries(}
\newcommand\postmybox{)\egroup}

\premybox hello\postmybox
```

However, `\mbox` and `\fbox`, and other macros cannot be used like this. See [TeX Hacks's Blog](http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2011/01/better-mbox-and-fbox.html) for new definitions of `\mbox` and `\fbox` which allow this usage.

---

You can use `environ` package to get the content between two macros. And this simpler TeXnique is also useful:

```
\def\precode #1\postcode{something about #1}
```

Comment: @egreg and Leo: Thank you both! In this case I‘ll us another way: defining an internal command that takes the argument of `\mymacro` like `\enclosecode{#1}`. Both answers are useful, but I think Leo’s matches my question a little better since `\fbox` was only a place holder, so I’ll accept his answer …

Answer (score 14):

You can't because `\fbox` is defined by

```
\newcommand\fbox[1]{%
  \leavevmode\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \color@begingroup\kern\fboxsep{#1}\kern\fboxsep\color@endgroup}%
  \@frameb@x\relax}
```

With `\mymacro{Text}` you do `\precode Text\postcode` which becomes

```
\fbox\bgroup Text\egroup
```

But `\bgroup` is *not* an argument delimiter here: only *explicit* braces are. So `\bgroup` is taken as `#1` and you get the wrong token list.

If the `color` package is not loaded, `\color@begingroup` and `\color@endgroup` are defined to be `\relax`, so what you get next is

```
\leavevmode\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \color@begingroup\kern\fboxsep{\bgroup}\kern\fboxsep\color@endgroup}%
  \@frameb@x\relax Text\egroup
```

Inside `\hbox`, `\bgroup` acts as a group delimiter and is balanced by the `}` just next to it. The final `\egroup` closes the `\hbox{`, so this explains why you don't get any output.

If the `color` package is loaded, `\color@begingroup` becomes `\begingroup` and `\color@endgroup` becomes `\endgraf\endgroup`; if you try, you'll get an error, because the groups are not properly balanced.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by lying to TeX about what you mean by `\precode` and `\postcode`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% egreg's clever macros
\def\obrace{\iftrue{\else}\fi}
\def\cbrace{\iffalse{\else}\fi}

\def\precode#1\postcode{%
 \edef\next{\noexpand\fbox\obrace\unexpanded{#1}\cbrace}%
 \next
}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\precode#1\postcode}

\begin{document}
 \mymacro{Text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course it works, but I can't see why the simpler `\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\fbox{#1}}` can't be considered. Here this trick is clearly overkill.

Comment: I interpreted the question to mean that he needed the syntax `\precode#1\postcode` for other reasons.